# Is it possible to run viber on an android emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, voip, viber

There isnt yet any viber version for PC, i would like to run this on the home pc (evtl. using an android emulator), is this possible? since viber registration base on the phonenumber and the confermation is done by sending an smscode to the client phonenumber, how would an emulator handle this issue?

can anybody recommend an emulator which can be attached to an existing phone number? any alternative ideas?

thanx

Comment: I strongly recommend choosing a voip provider that supports open standards: SIP, jingle, or H323. That way you'll have much less compatibility problems and can use the service from any device any way you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

You can download official Android emulator from
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html

And install Viber on it normally, simply put a real phone number of a phone you have around, once the SMS is recieved put the code in the Viber app in emulator.

But this doesn't go for WhatsApp.